# Hiding apps and or models by role in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I've done some research on this, but it seems a lot of posts dealing with permissions are quite old.  Essentially I'd like to know the following:

- Is it possible to hide apps and or models in django admin by role?  So for instance a blogger using the django admin to make blogs would only see the blog model and not see any of the other models or apps?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: When you go to Auth->Users in your admin panel, you can enable or disable add/change/delete privileges for every model that is in the admin. When you remove all three privileges from a user, they will not be able to 'see' that model. What are you specifically asking for?

Answer (score 3):

build groups, and put users in some group, users only could see what they could manage,other app or models are hide automatically

Answer (score 1):

you can overwrite get_model_perms method for ModelAdmin if you have some more fancy rules

```python
def get_model_perms(self, request):
    ## check if the request.user should see model, if not:
    return {'change': False, 'add': False}
```